# How to access the values (or keys) output by reducers in the main program of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Assume each Reducer outputs an integer as its value (or key). Is there any way to have access to those values (or keys) (to sum them up, for example) in the main program of Hadoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your output format? If you're using SequenceFileOutput then you can use the SequenceFile.Reader class to open the part-r-xxxxx files in your main program after the job has completed. For example a job that outputs `<Text, IntWritable>`, you can sum the values as follows:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
Text key = new Text();
IntWritable value = new IntWritable();
long total = 0;
for (FileStatus fileStat : fs.globStatus(new Path("/user/jsmith/output/part-r-*"))) {
  SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, fileStat.getPath(), getConf());
  while (reader.next(key, value)) {
    total = value.get();
  }
  reader.close();
}
```

For TextOutputFormat, the following will probably do it (replace the contents of the for loop):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(fileStat.getPath())));
String nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  String tokens[] = nextLine.split("\t");
  total += Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I'm using `TextOutputFormat` as my output format?

Comment: Added a simple solution for TextOutputFormat